# Format array content into a series of strings and output to .csv in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, format, mbed

I have been trying to figure out what the best way to do this would be, but haven't quite found an answer yet. I have a float array full of data collected from an inertial sensor and I would like to put it into the right format and output it to a CSV file. I'm using an mbed microcontroller with a local file system to store the file. It's the part about getting the format right that is confusing me at the minute.
I'd like my gyroscope/accelerometer values to be displayed in rows such as:

```
gx1, gy1, gz1, ax1, ay1, az1
gx2, gy2, gz2, ax2, ay2, az2
gx3, gy3, gz3, ax3, ay3, az3
```

I think these values first need to be converted to char before being written to the file, so I will need to do that and store them in a new array of type char. That's where I get confused, because I don't just want to copy the data into this new array all at once (thinking of using a for loop and spritf()) but I also want it to be formatted as displayed above, with the right breaks between rows.

The function that writes the content of the array to the file takes the array, its types size, the array size and the file object.

```
    fwrite(converted_array, sizeof(char), sizeof(converted_array), FileObject);
```

What would be the best way to make sure that the array content is formatted like I want it to be?

Comment: Perhaps `fprintf`?

Comment: Formatted output into CSV in C++ not found in the Web? :-) :-) :-) [google "c++ write csv"](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%2B%2B+write+csv)

Comment: OT: Although CSV is probably "Comma Separated Values", I usually separate columns with `'\t'`. Excel (as well as numerous other tools) like this as well.